# Qt Designer не нашёлся в PyQt5-tools

Tags: python, qt-designer

Новичок в программировании. Установила PyQt5-tools. Не нашла там designer.exe. Поэтому скачала отдельно Qt Designer.Создала файл .ui, вроде конвертировала в .py,добавила туду же где файл программы, но при запуске появляется окошко вроде про то, что Qt не инициализировано. В командной строке набираю import qt, пишет ошибку.Как поняла можно пользоваться Qt Designer только из PyQt5-tools,но не могу найти.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from new import Ui_MainWindow  # импорт нашего сгенерированного файла 
с именем label
import sys


class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mywindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = mywindow()
application.show()

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашла qt designer в pyqt5-tools, но всё-равно выскакивает то же окошко

Comment: покажите текст ошибки

Comment: вставила в вопрос код с ошибкой

Comment: @КристинаШевченко попробуйте перестановить именно qt не tools.

Answer (score 0):

Я сталкивался с подобной ошибкой. У меня проблема была в наличии русских букв в пути до PyQt-библиотек (*правда, в моём случае это был PySide2, но разница небольшая*).

Мне помог данный код

```
dirname = os.path.dirname(PyQt5.__file__)
plugin_path = os.path.join(dirname, 'plugins', 'platforms')
os.environ['QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH'] = plugin_path
```